# Math and form fields, getting NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, math

I'm updating a receipt based on user input in a form next to it.

**My problem** is that I think I'm dealing with text values instead of integers, since some math I'm doing results in NaN, while they display just fine separate with console.log

I collect three values and then try to multiply them for presenting in the receipt. This returns NaN.

The code so far:

```
$('fieldset').on('change', function(){

    group = $(this).attr('title');

    switch(group){
        case "dr":
            var name = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('label');
            var value = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('value');
            var weeks = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-weeks');
            var copies = $(this).find('input').val();

            //Only update the receipt when both are set (separate fields)           
            if(name != "" && copies != ""){
                produkter.push([name, value*weeks*copies]);
                receipt(produkter);
        }

        break;

        [other cases...]
    }

// Accepts an array with a name and a price sum.
function receipt(produkter){
    produkter.sort();

    $('.receipt li').remove(); // Clears the current receipt.

    for (var i = 0; i < produkter.length; i++) {
        $('.kvitto').append(
                '<li><span class="item">' + produkter[i][0] + '</span><span class="price">' + produkter[i][1] + '</span></li>');
    }

    console.log(produkter);
}

<fieldset title="dr">

    <label>DR format</label>
    <select>
        <option selected label="dr16" data-weeks="52" value="0,327">
            DR 16 sides</option>
        <option label="dr8" data-weeks="52" value="0,214">
            DR 8 Tab</option>
        <option label="drFF" data-weeks="52" value="0,352">
            DR Full format</option>
    </select>

    <br><br>

    <label>DR Copies</label>
    <input type="text" label="dr-copies" />

</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are indeed grabbing string values from the `attr` function. You need to convert them to integers, like this:

```
produkter.push([name, +value * +weeks * +copies]);
```

[**Basic example**](http://jsfiddle.net/7kUAN/)

Alternatively you can use `parseInt`, although it's not as succint:

```
produkter.push([name, parseInt(value, 10) * parseInt(weeks, 10) * parseInt(copies, 10)]);
```

Also, you need to cater for the attributes or values not being available by assigning a default value to the variables, like this:

```
var name = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('label') || 0;
var value = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('value') || 0;
var weeks = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-weeks') || 0;
var copies = $(this).find('input').val() || 0;
```

Comment: The + solution isn't working for me. Tried `var total = +value * +weeks * +copies;` and it outputs NaN with console.log

Comment: Did you also try providing default values for the variables as per the second part of my answer?

Comment: Found the problem with that though. Was using , instead of . for decimals. So now the + solution is working. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This line of code .val() will return a string/null or an array, giving you a NaN(Not a Number)

```
var copies = $(this).find('input').val();
```